# How to save an image instead of making a copy?

Tags: vb.net, jpeg, bmp, encoder, system.drawing.imaging

I've been tasked with reducing the quality of pictures on a network drive's file/folder system.

Code:

```
    Dim bmp1 As New Bitmap("U:\Image1.jpg")
    Dim jpgEncoder As ImageCodecInfo = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Dim myEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality
    Dim myEncoderParameters As New EncoderParameters(1)

    Dim myEncoderParameter As New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50&)
    myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter
    bmp1.Save("U:\Image1.jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters)
```

I get the following error: "A generic error occured in the GDI+".
Is there anyway to save instead of copying to another file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The file remains locked until you dispose of the bitmap.  You could save to "...jpg.new", dispose, then delete the original, rename the new.  The code shown isnt disposing though

Comment: Simple enough thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your code locks the file until `bmp1` is disposed. That's why you can't save to the original path.

Here's the way I use to load an image from file without actually locking the file:

```
    Dim bmp1 As Bitmap
    Using bmpTmp As New Bitmap("U:\Image1.jpg")
        bmp1 = New Bitmap(bmpTmp)
    End Using
```

Using this you'll be able to save directly to the original file path:

```
    '
    '
    bmp1.Save("U:\Image1.jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters)
    bmp1.Dispose()
```

Hope that helps :)